# terraform 1.0.0 strange message about github repository ETAG changed

Tags: github, terraform, terraform-provider-github

terraform 1.0.0

`terraform plan` displays the following message

```sh
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform
apply":

  # module.webrefresh-wordpress.github_repository.repository[0] has been changed
  ~ resource "github_repository" "repository" {
      ~ etag                   = "W/\"0a6acc64db34a0ae0d3ed9e6931dcc845ad0cf5f60113a6df4749c111b20a93a\"" -> "W/\"d1955c8eecde028f7360e767340e809796f6fb18b3c0a6bb0091d395334029df\""
        id                     = "test-webrefresh-wordpress"
        name                   = "test-webrefresh-wordpress"
        # (26 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant
attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to
these changes.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.
```

**So how to get rid of it?**

Tried with  `terraform apply -refresh-only` but it didn't help.

this is my tf code block:

```
resource "github_repository" "repository" {
  count       = length(local.to_create_repositories)
  name        = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].name
  description = title(local.to_create_repositories[count.index].description)

  visibility             = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].github_visibility
  has_issues             = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].has_issues != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].has_issues : true
  has_wiki               = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].has_wiki != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].has_wiki : true
  allow_merge_commit     = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].allow_merge_commit != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].allow_merge_commit : true
  allow_rebase_merge     = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].allow_rebase_merge != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].allow_rebase_merge : true
  delete_branch_on_merge = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].delete_branch_on_merge != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].delete_branch_on_merge : true
  auto_init              = local.to_create_repositories[count.index].auto_init != null ? local.to_create_repositories[count.index].auto_init : true
  archive_on_destroy     = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [etag]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is being tracked](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/796) in the [`github` provider](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/) as an issue relying on some upstream behaviour to be considered.

The [upstream issue in Terraform core](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28803) is particularly worth reading about to see why this is happening.

In your case as long as you don't have anything referencing the `etag` output (which would be surprising) then you can safely ignore this as it's just a computed attribute. You can also remove that `lifecycle.ignore_changes = [etag]` block because it doesn't impact computed attributes as it's not something settable by that resource.